# How to create regular expression to match the end of word in Java?

Tags: java, regex

Need regex for matching `{` character and every line that ends with this character. For example: `(isMoving){`

Tried:

```
^.?\{$
```

but it works only for single `{`

Comment: If you want to match start/end of line in multiline input, use multiline [flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html): `"(?m)^.*\\{$"`

Comment: If you want to only match whether the line ends with `{`, then you can use `{$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.?` means zero or one character. You want to match zero or more. Also the curly brace is a special regex character that is used for quantifying the occurrences of a certain pattern, and so it should be escaped:

```
^.*\{$
```

Answer (score 2):

The Java string representation of the regex you want is `".*\\{"` for use like

```
if (lineText.matches(".*\\{")) { ... }
```

A good place to experiment with such things is [RegexPlanet's Java page](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)